# How do i get solve value error while using migrate command in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on exam-app using django frmaework and my make migration command is working properly but migrate command is giving error

I have used Django frmawork but migration command givig error
(ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Super Admin')

this is my models.py file:

```
`import uuid
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, 
BaseUserManager
from django.db import models

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, password, **kwargs):
    if not email or not password:
        raise ValueError('User must have a username and password')

    user = self.model(
        email=CustomUserManager.normalize_email(email),
        **kwargs
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()

    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
    user = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)

    user.is_admin = True
    user.is_staff = True
    user.save()

    return user
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

SUPER_ADMIN = 1
STUDENT = 2
TEACHER = 3
ROLE_CHOICES = (
    (STUDENT, 'Student'),
    (SUPER_ADMIN, 'Super Admin'),
    (TEACHER , 'Teacher'),
)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
email = models.EmailField(null=False, unique=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# Add custom fields here
api_token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
token_created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
role = models.SmallIntegerField(choices = ROLE_CHOICES, null = True)

objects = CustomUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

def get_full_name(self):
    return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

def get_short_name(self):
    return self.first_name

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_staff

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return self.is_staff

def api_token_reset(self):
    self.api_token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('created_on',)
    db_table = 'users'

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.get_full_name()`
```

this is views.py file:

```
`from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import FormView

@login_required
def home(request):
return render(request, 'index.html')

def signupchoice(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'teacher' in request.POST:
        #role = "Teacher"
        print("hey Teacher")

        return redirect('signup')
    elif 'student' in request.POST:
        #role = "Student"
        print("hey student")

        return redirect('signup')

return render(request, 'signupchoice.html')

def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        return redirect('index')
else:
    form = SignUpForm()
#print(role)
return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})

def index(request):
return render(request, "index.html")

class LoginView(FormView):
form_class = AuthenticationForm
template_name = 'login.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
    password = form.cleaned_data['password']
    user = authenticate(username  = username, password = password)
    print(user.role)

    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect("index")
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)`
```

this is the error while running command -python manage.py migrate

```
`Operations to perform:
 Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, exam_app, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying exam_app.0003_auto_20190708_1935...Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 122, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 114, in alter_field
super().alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, strict=strict)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 509, in alter_field
old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 311, in _alter_field
self._remake_table(model, alter_field=(old_field, new_field))
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 170, in _remake_table
'default': self.quote_value(self.effective_default(new_field))
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 224, in effective_default
default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 767, in get_db_prep_save
return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 762, in get_db_prep_value
value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/home/firestorm/Desktop/exam_app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1826, in get_prep_value
return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Super Admin'`
```

this is migration file:

```
`from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('exam_app', '0002_user_role'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='user',
        name='role',
        field=models.SmallIntegerField(choices=[('Student', 'Student'), ('Super Admin', 'Super Admin'), ('Teacher', 'Teacher')], default='Super Admin'),
    ),
]
```

`

Comment: Can you share the relevant migration file. Likely the default value is simply a string for a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: added migration file

Comment: That is not the correct file. You need to post 0003_auto_20190708_1935, which apparently is the one that added the `role` field.

Comment: sorry ,please check the updated file

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, for some reason your migration file 0003_auto_20190708_1935 does not reflect the code: the field choice values are strings ('Student', etc) and not integers as in your code.

Presumably you created that migration before changing the code to use integers. You should remove that migration file and all following ones in that app, then re-run `makemigrations`.